# How do I get a value from a database using Oledb, I keep getting a DBNull exception?

Tags: c#, dbnull

```
int weaponDamage = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[randomItem][2]);
// dt= DataTable
// randomItem = randomly chooses a row from the datatable
```

That code throws

> "InvalidCastException was unhandled, Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types".

Yes I am using the correct column and yes the entire column has values. The odd thing is sometimes the program ran, but then next time it gives the exception again. Could the problem lie with my Data Type in the database? It is set to Number and the Field Size property to Integer

Answer (score 1):

Try some mitigation:

```
int weaponDamage = 0;

if (dt.Rows[randomItem][2] != DBNull.Value){ // I think, I'm doing this from memory.
    if (int.TryParse(dt.Rows[randomItem][2].ToString(), out weaponDamage){
        // Do whatever you need.
    }
}
```

Check that the column has a value other then NULL. Then do a safe-cast of that value into an int.

There's no reason why you should randomly be getting a value one time, and then a NULL the next to be honest. That would imply that the data in the table is changing, or you are looking at different rows of data? Not sure, but I'd add some defensive coding in there to help.

Answer (score 0):

What if you print the returned value first to see if it is a numeric, a string, a random object. You should also use proper try/catch blocks to avoid unhandled exceptions.